# Why does Electron Application not build sometimes?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have built an electron app. The folder structure is as follows,

```
App
  js
    script.js
  css
  db
  node_modules
  views
  package.json
  main.js
```

I have included the js files in the below form,
In html,

```
<head>
    <script src= "../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src= "../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "../css/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
stuff..............
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
```

When I build the package using electron-packager, the build is successful. But when I run the application, the functionalities written in script.js are not working.

**Update 1**
In my script.js, I have written the following code

```
var Datastore = require('nedb')
  , db = new Datastore({ filename: 'db/data.db', autoload: true });
const fs = require('fs');
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

$(document).ready(function(){
    pricing_view();shipping_view();etr_view();cost_view();
})
stuff .................
$("#percentage,#channel_name,#brand").bind('keyup mouseup', function   
() {
    populate();
   });
```

**Update 2:**
I used devtools to find the error. It's saying nedb module not found.

Everything will work fine when I run using npm start. But after build, functions in script.js not work.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe show us what's inside the `script.js` file?

Comment: I have show some code inside script.js

Comment: Are you using Webpack at all? Have you tried [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild)? I only mention that because it is possible the dependencies are not being bundled when you package the app.

Comment: No @unseen_damage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after 1 day of trying and reading the documentation of electron-packager. When packaging with electron-packager, change the **`devDependencies`** to **`dependencies`** in the **package.json**. That's because electron-packager looks for dependencies instead of devDependencies.

So, before trying to package the app, either rename the devDependencies to dependencies or **`npm install package_name --save`** .

** Note: Do not use `--save-dev` when packaging using electron-packager, as `-dev` will make the dependencies development dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the devtools temporarily in the menu for the bundled app and see if there are errors in the networks or console section.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your script like this:

```
<script>
    require('../js/script.js');
</script>
```